# Есть ли разница при обучении агента на CPU или GPU? Unity MLAgents

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Вопрос касаемо обучения ИИ. Насколько лучше идёт обучение на видеокарте чем на процессоре? У меня видеокарта не поддерживает Cuda 3.5, поэтому не могу проверить. Обучаю на 4-ёх ядерном процессоре, 5000 шагов занимает в среднем 500 секунд. Вот и хочется узнать, если приобрету новую видеокарту, то время на обучение уменьшится?

Comment: ну MLAgents может использовать GPU для обучения, а время обучения зависит от характеристик видеокарты напрямую

Comment: @Acinit а большая будет разница если обучать к примеру на RTX3060 или на процессоре core i3-8100?  Я бы приобрёл новую видеокарту если в этом есть смысл, т.к. мне нужно закончить проект.

Comment: не могу сказать точно, так как не обучал ни на одной из представленных моделей видеокарты и процессора, но что-то мне подсказывает, что да